# R function error when using a second & in a subset vector

Tags: r, runtime-error

Hello I am new to stack overflow and have a R query.

I am editing some existing code to analyse some data for a report.

The existing code is:

```
bar_lib <- make_table(col_type = 'multi_yn', multi_cols = Bar_lib_cols,inclNA=TRUE, title = 'Barriers to using public library services', subsetvec = (!is.na(DATA$sclibrary) & DATA$sclibrary=='No'))
```

The above code works and produces a table.

Below is the edited code I am trying to analyse the variable barlib07:

```
subsetvec = (!is.na(DATA$sclibrary) & DATA$sclibrary=='No'& DATA$barlib07='Yes'))
```

With this code I am getting an error:

> Error in !is.na(DATA$sclibrary) & DATA$sclibrary == "No" &
>   DATA$barlib07 = "Yes" :    could not find function "&<-"

I am not sure how to resolve this.

Please help.

Thanks,

Analyst001

Comment: Look at the error message, which points you to `DATA$barlib07='Yes'`. You have `=`, which is an assignment (also written as `<-` as is shown in the error message), instead of `==`, which is a comparison. This is basically a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to `subsetvec = (!is.na(DATA$sclibrary) & DATA$sclibrary == 'No' & DATA$barlib07 == 'Yes'))`